# Create an aspx page from a C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I wish to get a direction on how to create a dynamic asp.net page from code-behind (C#).
For instance, a user uploads a picture named "flower.jpg", I wish to create a customized and dynamic asp.net page which will be named "flower.jpg.aspx".
I have no idea how to do that and I really need a direction.

Comment: We are not here to write your work for you

Comment: Please post here your problem only related to your programming !

Comment: Start by analyzing your task and what you need to solve it. You have a file upload, which you need to store in a database. Create a generic page which will contain the picture and also store the additional info in the database and display it with labels, which will be loaded with info by the controllers. Not always the most obvious answer is what you need to do.

Comment: Yes, I know that but I have no idea how to start with the generic page thingy. I just need something to start with, a class name or something. How would I be able to do something alone that I never learned before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't think you need to create a new page, this is a fairly simple question to solve if you use the following :

- Take advantage of the fact that you can do dynamic operations in ASP.NET
- Upload all files into a DB, File, etc and keep a reference to them
- Create a class that will contain the metadata for the upload
- When the data is required, call a page that shows the metadata of the items the user has uploaded(e.g Name, Location, Time, etc)
- User [ASP.NET Routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) if you want the link to reflect the photo name

Answer (score 0):

You should not create aspx page for each image, because if you did that and you will have to put the aspx page in your virtual directory which will cause the site to restart.

You can save the image to a database or file system and store the image attributes like extension, file name, size in the database and have a page to list the images and another one page to view the image details.

The details page will have an `<img src="URL to the Image"/>` tag which will display the image and some other attributes.

If it is a must to have the page with a .aspx extension then you can use routing if you are using MVC, you will have a single MVC Controller and action but you will have a route in the shape : {controller}/{action}/{image}.aspx

Comment: I suspect he's talking about url rewriting

Answer (score 0):

By checking your description I think what you want to do is to create some photo gallery page. You may be interested in those resources:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14290/Simple-Photo-Gallery-With-ASP-NET-2-0
http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/a-simple-asp-net-photo-album
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21075/Gallery-Server-Pro-An-ASP-NET-Gallery-for-Sharing

In the web.config setpath to your images:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="PicRootPath" value="~/PICStore/"/>
    <add key="PicRootDefaultPath" value="~/PicStore/Default/" />
</appSettings>
```

Create a class `ContentInfoLoader` such as:

```
Configuration rootWebConfig = 
    WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/");
if(0<rootWebConfig.AppSettings.Settings.Count)
{
    KeyValueConfigurationElement picRootElement = 
        rootWebConfig.AppSettings.Settings["PicRootPath"];
    if(null!=picRootElement)
    {
        _picRootPath=picRootElement.Value;
    }

    picRootElement = rootWebConfig.AppSettings.Settings["PicRootDefaultPath"];
    if (null != picRootElement)
    {
        _picRootDefaultPath = picRootElement.Value;
    }
}
```

Then a method to get the images:

```
public string[] GetGalleryPaths(string picRootRealPath) 
{
    if (Directory.Exists(picRootRealPath))
    {
        return Directory.GetDirectories(picRootRealPath);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public string[] GetPhotoList(string galleryName, string picRootRealPath)
{
    string galleryPath=picRootRealPath + "\\" + galleryName + "\\pics";
    if (Directory.Exists(galleryPath))
    {
        return Directory.GetFiles(galleryPath,"*.JPG");
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```